# What's the difference between an associative entity and an entity?

Tags: database

I noticed in one of my exercises that an Order (Attributes OrderID, description...etc)  requires a buyer, seller, and an account number which are stored as other entities. I'm wondering why Order is stored as an entity rather than an associative entity.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of an associative entity is it is something we normally wouldn’t identify as as entity but which we need in order to link things together, see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity

Here the Order is a business entity in itself so the term wouldn’t apply. Entities can be artifacts of business processes as well as concrete things.

Answer (score 0):

In all implementations of SQL (that I know of), there isn't a separate type of entity for "Associative Entities". They are simply regular entities with Foreign Key constraints.

There's quite a bit of information that can be "lost" in translation when going from something like an ER Diagram to actual DB schemas, but all you can do is try your best to reconcile the two.

**Edit**

Terminology changes too: Entities become Tables, and Attributes become Columns